# How to open or execute Powershell scripts in Administrator Elevated Mode without UAC prompt?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, uac

How to open or execute Powershell scripts in Administrator Elevated Mode without UAC prompt?

Use case:

I have over 100+ Standalone Windows Servers that needs `SeNetworkLogonRight` modification to remove users and add a specific application user to the group.

If there was an AD I would of gotten this done long ago so please do not suggest as there is data privacy issues. :)

Steps in my scripts:

1. Import-Module UserRights.psm1
2. Revoke-UserRight
3. Grant-UserRight

I've spent the last few days researching but nothing really works.  I tried schtask, vbscripts, and other posts with no success.

There are 5-10 users to modify per server.

Comment: Ok, so now if I can run Powershell in admin mode to run this adjustment:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-switch-UAC-level-0ac3ea11

Would the schtask be able to run PowerShell or scripts in elevated mode?  If so, I can utilize the UAC switch script above to disable UAC, then renable once done automatically.

Comment: You don't have to disable UAC. Could you be more specific on how you want to invoke your scripts (remoting into the machines, logon locally, scheduled tasks,...)?

Comment: hi Thomas, use case, all servers are remote.   Can I create a schtask to run a PowerShell script in Elevated mode without UAC prompt?  I need the command line + syntax so I can automate this to every server without logging into each...  There was some examples out there and was not able to get it working successfully.  thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so we need some sort of remoting here. Do you want to execute your exact scripts regularly or only once? Do you have the credentials of an account on each machine that is a member of the "Administrators" group? If so, are they the same on each machine?

Comment: Hi Thomas, that is correct...  would love to do it remotely but at the same time, I also want to be able to run the schtask command if I logon locally.   There is an account on every machine that is a member of the administrators group and it's the same account.  The script will be a one time thing.  I'm not looking to pass through a username and password in the script though...  that's too dangerous.  If I have to logon locally to a machine and run a schtasks command, I would rather do that than to pass credentials.  thanks Thomas.